# Why my mail service api spring isnt working?

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, jakarta-mail

The error:

> java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out; message exceptions (1) are:
> Failed message 1: jakarta.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
> nested exception is:
> java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out] with root cause

> java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
> at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedRead(NioSocketImpl.java:283) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implRead(NioSocketImpl.java:309) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.read(NioSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$1.read(NioSocketImpl.java:803) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketInputStream.read(Socket.java:966) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:484) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.readHeader(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:478) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:160) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:111) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1506) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1421) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:455) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:426) ~[na:na]
> at org.eclipse.angus.mail.util.SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket(SocketFetcher.java:662) ~[jakarta.mail-2.0.3.jar:na]
> at org.eclipse.angus.mail.util.SocketFetcher.startTLS(SocketFetcher.java:563) ~[jakarta.mail-2.0.3.jar:na]
> at org.eclipse.angus.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:2168) ~[jakarta.mail-2.0.3.jar:na]
> at org.eclipse.angus.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:741) ~[jakarta.mail-2.0.3.jar:na]
> at jakarta.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:345) ~[jakarta.mail-2.0.3.jar:na]
> at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.connectTransport(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:480) ~[spring-context-support-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
> at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:399) ~[spring-context-support-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
> at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:350) ~[spring-context-support-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
> at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender.send(JavaMailSender.java:101) ~[spring-context-support-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
> at apiemailsender.service.EmailService.sendEmail(EmailService.java:32) ~[classes/:na]
> at apiemailsender.controllers.EmailController.sendEmail(EmailController.java:20) ~[classes/:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
> at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:255) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
> at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:188) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:830) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:914) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
> at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:6.0]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
> at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:6.0]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
> at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
> at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
> at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
> at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]

I have no antivirus on my pc and try some things I've here on stack overflow but the program isn't working yet. I will show some snippets of my code:

```yaml
    aplications.yml: 

    spring:
  mail:
    host: email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
    port: 587
    username: ses-smtp-user.20240330-201531
    password: 
    properties:
      mail:
        smtp:
          auth: true
          starttls:
            enable: true
          connectiontimeout: 5000
          timeout: 300
          writetimeout: 5000
          ssl:
            protocols: TLSv1.2


server:
  port: 8081
-Djavax:
  net:
    debug=all:
```

My service class:

```java
@Service
public class EmailService {
    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender emailSender;

    public void sendEmail(Email email) throws MessagingException {
        MimeMessage message = emailSender.createMimeMessage();
        MimeMessageHelper mimeMessageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);
        mimeMessageHelper.setFrom(email.getFrom());
        mimeMessageHelper.setTo(email.getTo());
        mimeMessageHelper.setSubject(email.getSubject());
        mimeMessageHelper.setText(email.getText());

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.protocols", "TLSv1.2");

        emailSender.send(message);
    }
}
```

Can someone please help me?

I tried to start the program with debug

```yaml
-Djavax:
  net:
    debug=all:
```

But it doesn't work. Tried to add props in the service class but didn't work. Also I commented the `java.security` line

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, DTLSv1.0, RC4, DES, \
    MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224, 3DES_EDE_CBC, anon, NULL,
```

Still doesn't work

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the full stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Done. please take a look

Comment: How is this not a duplicate of your other question here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78249897/why-my-api-spring-aws-ses-isnt-working

Comment: @smac2020 dont get you, you're talking about my credentials? i hide the password